# Is there a Rails plugin or Ruby gem that offers similar functionality to Django's built-in Admin Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reading about Django, I saw this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin - the fancy simple to use admin page that django can magically create for you.

Is there a plugin or gem offering similar functionality in Rails.

Are there any plans to make Rails do this for you in the future?

Comment: Because Rails and Django came out from different needs, I don't see that this feature will be available in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/), it has some really nice functionality for auto-creating a quick admin GUI

Comment: thanks.  this is what I was looking for, nice to see there are some alternatives to play about with too.